# Labeling edges not working as described in manual?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is from page 274 of the tikz/pgfmanual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz \graph [quick] { "a" --["foo"] "b"[x=1] };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When I try to `lualatex` this file, I get the following:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/"foo"' and I am going to
ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.8 \tikz \graph [quick] { "a" --["foo"] "b"[x=1]
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to load the `quotes` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}%<- added

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz \graph [quick] { "a" --["foo"] "b"[x=1] };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]